# parsing output and passing in specific line into following command

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-web-services, sed

I am trying to parse an output from aws cli and pass it into another argument. I am trying to accomplish this with sed and am stuck on how to approach it, I have read other posts but can't seem to figure it out.

output:

```
{
 "LoadBalancers": [
  {
      "Type": "network",
      "Scheme": "internet-facing",
      "IpAddressType": "ipv4",
      "VpcId": "vpc-3ac0fb5f",
      "AvailabilityZones": [
          {
              "LoadBalancerAddresses": [
                  {
                      "IpAddress": "35.161.207.171",
                      "AllocationId": "eipalloc-64d5890a"
                  }
              ],
              "ZoneName": "us-west-2b",
              "SubnetId": "subnet-5264e837"
          }
      ],
      "CreatedTime": "2017-10-15T22:41:25.657Z",
      "CanonicalHostedZoneId": "Z2P70J7EXAMPLE",
      "DNSName": "my-network-load-balancer-5d1b75f4f1cee11e.elb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
      "LoadBalancerName": "my-network-load-balancer",
      "State": {
          "Code": "provisioning"
      },
      "LoadBalancerArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:123456789012:loadbalancer/net/my-network-load-balancer/5d1b75f4f1cee11e"
  }
 ]
}
```

The string i am trying to capture is

```
arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:123456789012:loadbalancer/net/my-network-load-balancer/5d1b75f4f1cee11e
```

and pass it into the following command:

`aws elbv2 delete-load-balancer --load-balancer-arn <the arn extracted from the previous output>`

If you provide a solution a small explanation would be helpful as well. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If the output is coming from another `aws` command, there may be a `--query` option you can use to get just that value in the first place.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 3):

If the output is json format, `sed` is not recommended to parse the json/xml...input.

You can use `jq` in shell, for your example, you can do:

```
..cmd to get yourOutput..|jq '.LoadBalancers[0].LoadBalancerArn'
```